# Porque meu getbands está retornando 'L'?

Tags: python-3.x

Eu trabalhando com imagens e estou filtrando imagens com transparência. Estou usando a função `getbands()` do Pillow. Porém esta imagem está me retornando : `('L',)` enquanto eu só esperava: `('R','G', 'B')` e `('R','G', 'B', 'A')`.

O que é exatamente uma imagem `L`? procurei em vários lugares mas não consegui saber o significado disso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L é "Level", um canal só de cinza.

Este tipo de coisa é mera questão de estudar o manual da biblioteca utilizada, provavelmente a PIL/Pillow no caso.

Os Modos (que por consequência definem as bandas) mais comuns são esses:

- `1` (1-bit por pixel, branco e preto)
- `L` (8-bit por pixel, tons de cinza)
- `P` (8-bit por pixel, referenciando a uma paleta de cores)
- `RGB` (3x8-bit por pixel, um canal de cada cor)
- `RGBA` (4x8-bit por pixel, idem à anterior + transparência)
- `CMYK` (4x8-bit por pixel, em cores de pigmento)
- `YCbCr` (3x8-bit por pixel, formato comum em vídeo, baseado em desvio de cores)
- `LAB` (3x8-bit por pixel, outro formato baseado em luminância e desvio  )
- `HSV` (3x8-bit por pixel, tonalidade, saturação e valor)

Manual: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html